# Shift Registers: Array of LED Mirroring

Tags: arduino, led

I'm doing an activity and I need help.
So I'm practicing about shift registers...
The goal I want to achieve is I want to light up one by one in sequence all the 16 leds.

But what happens is the second set of 8 leds connected to the 2nd shift register is copying the sequence of the first set of 8 leds connected to the 1st shift register.

In other words, the result of the first 8 leds is also the result of the 2nd 8 leds.  It is mirroring. Why is this so? given that I connected the QS' of the first register to the D of the second shift register. I'm confused. Maybe a Proteus bug?

Anyways here's my code

```
unsigned char sequence[] = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128};
unsigned char sequence2[]= {128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384}; //added

int latchPin = 8;  //Pin connected to STR(pin 1) of HEF4094
int clockPin = 12; //Pin connected to CP(pin 3) of HEF4094
int dataPin = 11;  //Pin connected to D(pin 2) of HEF4094

void setup() {    

  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{ 
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)   
  { //added
        if(i<8){
           shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, sequence[i]); //Send the data
           digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH); //Pull latch HIGH to send data
         }
         else if (i>=8){
            shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, sequence2[i]); //Send the data
          }
  }//added
}
```

and this my designed circuit.

Any help will be appreciated thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Arduino Reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/shiftout/), the `shiftOut()` function shifts data one full byte (8 bits) at a time. In the `for` loop in `loop()`, you call `shiftOut()` 16 consecutive times with the same data, thus clocking 16 copies of the same byte into your shift registers - thus the outputs of both shift registers will be mirrored.

Comment: ... which means you'll have to handle the shift pattern in your code and send out the two bytes of data after every change followed, I presume, by a strobe.

Comment: I added a second sequence

unsigned char sequence2[]= {128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384};

and this function    

else if (i>=8){
      shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, sequence2[i]); //Send the data
      }

so that their data wont be the same but still, the mirroring action happened

Comment: An else block is not a function, and because there are no if statements in your original code I have no idea where that would go. Please update your original post.

Comment: I already updated it.

Comment: This will produce the same mirroring problem, since now you are writing 8 copies of the same sequence consecutively. Think about it like this: everytime you want to update your output, shift out two bytes: first the one going to the second SR, then the one going to the first.

Comment: Also you may get some unexpected results, since you can't store a value greater than 255 in a char, which you appear to be doing in your declarations. Remember, one shift register doesn't know of the existence of the other one, so they know nothing of 16 bit numbers. Based on what the current value of i is, you can compute what each set of eight bits should be.

Comment: so with your given statement, I will going to use
two shiftout functions right?

1st shiftOut to the 2nd SR then 
2nd shiftOut to the 1st SR. 
?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I see similar problem as mine here:

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/6512/going-from-one-shift-register-to-two-shift-registers

Comment: I really don't understand how shifting works from one SR to another